# Is it possible to represent electrical components as classes in OOP design?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, simulation, programming

I was just studying my Electronics course, the topic of E-MOSFETs. And suddenly, it just got a question in my mind. Since that OOP teaches us to *program things like they are in real life objects*, is it possible to create OOP design which consists of electronic components in order to simulate them later on.

Do you know any source code to make me understand how to implement them?

Thank you.

**Note:** Found an example software program named as "Falstad's Circuit Simulator". More accurately, it's port to JavaScript. They have created every circuit component as a class within properties we know from physics. One can see the transistor's OOP representation [here](https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1/blob/master/src/com/lushprojects/circuitjs1/client/TransistorElm.java), and op-amp's representation [here](https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1/blob/master/src/com/lushprojects/circuitjs1/client/OpAmpElm.java). Thank you for all who replied to this question.

Comment: Of course it is possible. We can't recommend any particular source code, though.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Yet, for the simulation purposes they will have to be transformed to more compact and math-friendly form

Comment: Yes, why not? Circuit diagrams inside simulation programs are anyway nothing else but just graphs of connections between component terminals. You can use OOP or any other programming paradigm to achieve the same end result.

Comment: I wrote a simulator for a specific purpose several years ago, the component models were all objects in C#.

Comment: Null I just checked the ng-spice and KiCad's EEScheme's source-code, and couldn't see any representation of electronic components as classes. I wish to see an example, thought. Eugene Sh. So, you're saying that mostly simulation softwares doesn't care much about objects, instead they look for mathematical analysis. For example, how these systems are modular to every situation? I have been feeling that there has to be some "standardization" because of my programming background, I think. Justme Do you have a code example? I understood what you said, but cannot implement it.

Comment: @JohnD Have you uploaded it to git?

Comment: You should understand that such a software usually has a front-end and a back-end. On the front-end you can have a GUI, where you can draw your schematic, drag, drop and interconnect graphical representations of components. This thing is perfectly fitting into the "naive" OOP paradigm, where each component is an object. But then there is a simulation back-end, which will need to take this representation and transform it into a different representation, which can be OOP as well, but will have very different structure and will have completely different objects (like matrices, trees and such)

Comment: When Berkely SPICE was written, FORTRAN (probably FORTRAN-77) didn't have classes. Maybe it still doesn't. So SPICE is probably the wrong place to look ...  though it may still be the best place for implementation details.

Comment: @G.Koçmarlı I have not uploaded it to GIT, nor can I share the source code, sorry!

Comment: For those wanting to code a simulator, I can recommend "Circuit Simulation" by Farid Najm as a good place to start.  It doesn't go into OOP, but you can easily see how to implement a simulator in OOP if you follow along with the exercises.

Comment: Please note that using OOP does not mean you need to have a programming language like C++ where you define and instantiate objects. You can use OOP when writing plain C or assembly language even if the language is not supporting objects. Just like you can do non-OOP spaghetti code in almost any language. It's the methodology and idea that counts when implementing something, regardless of the language used to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a Yes and No. The Yes side would be that OOP can be used for anything, as can any other programming paradigm. But if we want to be OOP purists, I think the answer is actually no, because of the problem of global state. Either you need a "God object" for the circuit, or the component objects have to interrogate each other and change their internal states accordingly, effectively simultaneously. Which they can do, but it's not purist OOP. Whether, of course, anything really is is another question...

Answer (score 2):

The aim of object-oriented programming is to represent the interactions between objects in a clean, simple way.

What is your software doing? If you're designing an EDA tool for schematic capture or board layout, OOP might be a great fit. A resistor "**is a**" component, and it **has** properties like resistance, and so on. There are some open-source EDA tools out there with object-oriented code: just one example is [KiCad](https://www.kicad.org/) ([source](https://gitlab.com/kicad/code/kicad/-/tree/master/kicad)) written in C++.

If you're designing a simulation tool, the interactions between components become more complex and take on time domain (and/or frequency domain) aspects which require iterative numerical solutions that are not well-suited to object-oriented design (although the framework of the simulation tool can of course be object-oriented).

Answer (score 0):

for schematic capture OOP works well, but when it comes to simulation implementing basic rules like Kirchoffs laws needs the consideration of several circuit elements.

for this reason it is more common to see the schematic converted to a matrix for simulation.